# How do i make bootstrap typehead local search to Ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead, typehead

Maybe ask before , i don't know. i implement bootstrap typehead `0.9.3` with local search array , everything work fine , so i need to make this array in separate file `search.php` this is my local search array code

```
$('#state').typeahead({        
local: [
<?php 
     $resultState=$objGeneral->GetStates();
     while($rowStates=$resultState->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
     {
    echo "'".$rowStates[1]."',";
     }
 ?>
 ]
 });                                                                                                            
$('.tt-query').css('background-color','#fff');
```

Now I want to sparate this php code and call throgh ajax , i try this code but dose not work for me

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#state").typeahead({
    name : 'state',
    remote: {
        url : 'search.php'
    }

 });
});
```

in `seach.php` json array look like this

```
$objGeneral=new General(); 
$resultStates=$objGeneral->GetStates();
while($rowStates=$resultStates->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))   
{   
$State[]=$rowStates['name'];
}
echo json_encode($State);
```

Comment: What does "dose not work for me" mean? No typeahead? Does  `search.php` return the expected results?

Comment: its return all element in array  typehead but not result which i type

Comment: "not result which i type". That's not really a surprise because your search.php doesn't have any code in it to retrieve the value sent from the browser, or to use that to restrict the results of the query. You amend your query, probably with a WHERE clause which restricts results to those (partially?) matching what was typed in.

Comment: yes you are right but i have retrieve all states not where query . please tell how can i filter result from json array of ajax, any solution

Comment: much more efficient to filter it on the server IMO. Why transmit data you don't need? Waste of (user's paid-for) bandwidth.